# Mr. Robot: Logical contradiction in series finale

Tags: mr-robot

I feel that there is a logical inconsistency that occurs during the final storyline in Mr. Robot. To avoid spoilers:

> At the end of Mr. Robot, we learn that the "real" Elliot has been imprisoned in a make-believe world that "the mastermind" created to keep him busy. During one of the scenes in this world, we see Price as Angela's father. However, neither Elliot nor Angela knew that Price was her father when the make-believe world was created, which I think it supposed to be at the beginning of the series. So that shouldn't have been Price, that should have been who Elliot and Angela thought actually was her father (who we've met before).

Am I missing something here? Is there a simple explanation?

Comment: Do we actually know that Price is Angela's father in the real world? The revelation that he is her father occurs within Elliot's make-believe world, so maybe it is make believe as well.

Comment: There's no reason the "make-believe world" had to be created at some fixed date in the past and then be forced to operate logically. If the "mastermind" could create it, then he surely could also modify it.

Answer (score 3):

One possible explanation:
This loop world is created based on the real world experienced by the Mastermind Elliot. He even doesn't remember doing this. So, it's possible that anything constructed in this loop world is the ideal condition that the Mastermind wanted to have happened. The elements in it will and always changed according to the Mastermind's experiences.

We see that in this loop world, Zhi Zhang is the richest man (woman) in the world. And he/she had Whiterose foundation. Elliot is CEO at Allsafe. The whole world stuck at 5/9 every day. The real Elliot is kept here, with new elements in every loop.

So when the Mastermind goes into this loop world, what he sees is the accumulation of the knowledge that he experienced in the real world.